# Restoring large amounts of data from XML

Tags: android, xml, sqlite

I'm trying to chose best approach for this. What I have is an xml file that might consist up to 5000 nodes. Each holds 5 child nodes.

What I need is rewriting it to the sqlite database. Wouldn't it be overkill for weaker devices that might have like 128RAM if I'd translate those xml into collection of objects and then, using this collection insert them to sqlite database?

Or I rather shouldn't build the collection and insert values as I parse XML file?

It will be rare operation for user. It's all about restoring backup from xml to device's database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, do not build the collection in memory. Instead use an `AsyncTask` along with `PullParser`(which is currently, the best parser available in the Android libraries).

In the `doInBackground()` of your `AsyncTask`, parse out a batch(say 25) objects, then call `dbOpenHelper.bulkInsert()` to save the entire batch to your database at once.

Of course, here you'll have to add a bulk insert method to your SQLiteOpenHelper implementation to insert a bunch of rows at once.

You can find out how to write a Bulk Insert method for your SQLiteOpenHelper [HERE](http://notes.theorbis.net/2010/02/batch-insert-to-sqlite-on-android.html). For conciseness, I've added the core method needed.

```
try{
  db.beginTransaction();
  for each record in the list {
     do_some_processing();
     if (line represent a valid  entry) {
        db.insert(SOME_TABLE, null, SOME_VALUE);
     }
     some_other_processing();
  }
  db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} catch (SQLException e) {
} finally {
  db.endTranscation();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will take massive RAM if you load all xml at once (create a DOM from it). But you can use SAX, StAX, PullParser etc which will read file *node by node*, let you know when they hit an interesting node, and you can save that node to DB by an insert.

Pseudo code for Stream parsing all 5000 parent nodes, with DOM for each 5 child nodes :

```
while(not end node){
   Node n = Parser.readNextNode();
   saveIfInteresting(n);
}

saveIfInteresting(Node n){
   if(interesting){
     values = extractValues(n);
     db.insert(values);
   }
}

extractValues(Node n){
  //--just 5 child nodes, can do with a small DOM--
  Document d = buildDOM(n);
  for(Element e in d){
    Values.add(e.getText());
  }
  return values;

  //OR

  //---stream parse children too--
  while(not parent end node){
    Node n = Parser.readNext();
    if(n is required child){
      values.add(n.getText());
    }
  }
  return values;
}
```

Comment: So it would basically replace node object with next one after it's done with the previous one?

Comment: You pass a file stream to stream parser and call `next()` , on each `next()` it jumps to next element in file (depth first tree walking). With each `next()` parser's method's give info about the current node it is pointing to.

Comment: Thanks. Both answers solves the problem. However I love the batch idea. I'm sorry that I accept both answers. Take the vote up at least :)